# Consume Json service without mapping to a class

Tags: c#

I am consuming a service that returns a Json array.  (essentially it is a web request, and the output is the text of a json array.)  Is there a way I can get the results, and find what I need without making my own class to map it?

i.e.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Successfully_Parse_Json_Items_From_URL()
    {
        var content = GetHttpContent(new Uri("", "application/json"); //returns HttpContent
        string json = content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result; //Not sure what to do here.  id want this maybe to be an array of keyvalue pairs or something?
        //...code
    }
```

If my array was:

```
[{item1: "value", item2: "value"}]
```

I would be interested only in item 2.  I don't care what other items there are.

**Edit**

So I discovered that what I am looking for is a way to extract "item2" from:

```
[{item1: "value", fields: { item2: "value2"}}]
```

I tried doing:

```
JArray jsonArray = content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>().Result;
foreach(JObject obj in jsonArray){
    JArray jArray = (JArray)obj.SelectToken("fields"); //This throws an error about unable to case JObject to JArray.
}
```

**UPDATE**
I managed to get this working.

```
foreach(var obj in jsonArray){
    string item2 = (string)obj["fields"].SelectToken("item2");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use a library like Json.Net (http://json.codeplex.com/) to read the received Json string.

Json.Net allows you to parse arbitrary Json strings and treat it as a dynamic type. Then you can write your test like this:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
Assert.IsTrue(jObject.item2 == "value");
```

Comment: No it is not JObject, it is **JArray**

Comment: Hmm, JArray will give you the array directly while JObject will give you a json.net dynamic object that you must read. I suppose the assert must be rewritten, but the concept is still valid.

Comment: No  the concept is not valid. it would throw exception. If you don't know the type (single object or array) you should use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

Comment: Besides that your code wouldn't compile a) `jObject` should be declared as `dynamic` b) `jObject.item2` is not correct since it is an array. So there isn't any correct part in your answer.

Comment: I am having an issue actually with JArray.  I discovered that the JSON string has a nested array.  See edit above.